# Nothing happens and no errors binding data from sql server to textbox

Tags: textbox, sql-server-2016

Im trying tot start with a easy setup. I try to get de data into textboxes and start with the first step. For some reason I can't bind the data to the textbox and don't received any errors. Programming is running fine, but nothing is happening when I press the button.

I tested with gridview to check the connection and that seems to be working.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016 Express version, visual studio 2017, ASP and C#

What do I wrong? Wrong code? Connection blocked by the server?
.........................

**ASPX code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test3.aspx.cs" Inherits="test3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="281px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Start" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.............................

**The CS code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class test3 : System.Web.UI.Page

{

 public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\WDVEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=user;User ID=testaccount;Password=123test");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

    }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        SqlCommand com;
        string str;

        conn.Open();
        str = "select * from Company$ where Name = 'testuser'";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

.......................

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: your button click event is not bound. bind it onclick="click function on csharp" check code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button on aspx page is not bound to button click event on aspx.cs page. Check below code it will tell you how they got bounded -

**HTML ( ASPX PAGE ) CODE**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Start"  OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**CS CODE**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your Click Event Here
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I add the extra code but still nothing is happening. I add an extra event to check if an other label is amending the name and this seems to be working on the button click. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you tried debugging code. it may help to know actual problem

Comment: after updating button code to as provided in my answer you code worked for me. i only check it is coming on button click

Comment: why are you adding '$' to table name. you are using select * from Company$

Comment: Hi Heemanshu, it is working. The problem was indeed what you mention earlier. I checked it again and recreate the account. This solves the problem for me. About the $ sign. This will be automaticly done by the MS SQL server when you import data from an Excel document. I keep this sign, This will help me to identify if the data is coming from files or directly from other databases. Again many thanks for your help!